# hql error in select clause

Tags: java, hibernate

When I am using HQL select clause following error is occuring .student is mysql table.
**Error:
Hibernate: select studentcla0_.vStudentName as col_0_0_ from student studentcla0_
java.lang.String**

Below is Code:

```
public static void querySubject(Session session)
        {
            String sql_query="select stud.strStudentName from StudentClass as stud";
            Query query1=session.createQuery(sql_query);

        for(Iterator it=query1.iterate();it.hasNext();)
        {
            Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
            System.out.println("Subject Name:"+row[0]);

        }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is it hql or sql. If sql try:

```
session.createSQLQuery(...)
```

Comment: So I guess the exception is a ClassCast Exception on Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();

The query should return a list of String.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm - you have a table in your database called "student" and it has a column called "vStudentName" which is a string type of some sort? The mapping is complete, and has resulted in a translation to this SQL:

```
select studentcla0_.vStudentName as col_0_0_
from student studentcla0_
```

Does this run against your database directly, or does it error there as well?

Answer (score 0):

When you select a single value (be it property or entity), Hibernate will return that value directly; it will **not** be wrapped in an Object array. See details [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select). So your code should be:

```
for(Iterator it=query1.iterate(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    System.out.println("Subject Name:"+ it.next());
}
```